# How to import NLTK library in Hacker Rank

Tags: python-3.x

This is hacker rank code

```
#use stemming
import nltk 
#nltk.data.load('stopwords')
#import sys
from nltk .stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english", ignore_stopwords=True)
class StemmedCountVectorizer(CountVectorizer):
        def build_analyzer(self):
            analyzer = super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()
            return lambda doc: ([stemmer.stem(w) for w in analyzer(doc)])
    stemmed_count_vect = StemmedCountVectorizer(stop_words='english')

    text_mnb_stemmed = Pipeline([('vect', stemmed_count_vect),
    ...                      ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ...                      ('mnb', MultinomialNB(fit_prior=False)),
    ... ])
    text_mnb_stemmed = text_mnb_stemmed.fit(X_trainset, Y_trainset)
    predicted_mnb_stemmed = text_mnb_stemmed.predict(X_testset)

for i in predicted_mnb_stemmed:
    print(i)
```

Importing NLTK library is giving error.How to import it in hacker rank?[image]

Comment: It looks like a warning not an error

Comment: Actually it is a run time error.